Generic way of handling call to multiple api endpoints that use JWT
Setting up an application to call one of a handful of different client api endpoints, each of which use JWT.  However, as of now I dont know the specifics of how the specific client might implement JWT on their end.  Still, I think I could handle "most" scenarios if I extracted out the "most common" parameters used in both setting up the auth step to get a token, then a flag to put the token on the url (not common).  What kind of wrinkles (ignoring claims) could cause me to handle some specific client api call differently?
Note:  the config example is just for testing.  actual secrets would be kept elsewhere.
    {
      "ApiSettings": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://api.example.com",
        "AuthUrl": "https://api.example.com/auth/token",
        "ClientIdName": "client_id_field",
        "ClientIdValue": "your_client_id",
        "ClientSecretName": "client_secret_name",
        "ClientSecretValue": "client_secret_name",
        "TokenOnUrl" : false
      }
    }

